# Importing data table using Pandas - Exception: Index (columns 0) have duplicate values [nan]

Tags: io, pandas

I am new to `pandas` so please forgive me if I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't seem to find the answer in previous questions.

I'm trying to import a table into Pandas that has an arbitrary number of whitespaces as the delimiters.  Here's an example of the data:

```
*PRODUCT : Backscatter Ratio - 1064.0 nm ^

Altitude                  2010/03/23 17:01:00       2010/03/23 17:03:00       ...

1.50                      1                         1                         ...

4.50                      1                         1                         ...

.                         .                         .

.                         .                         .

.                         .                         .*
```

The actual size of the table is 1310 columns by 6009 rows.  I don't necessarily want to use the fixed width parser as the spacing might change for these tables in the future so I used the following:

```
df = pandas.io.parsers.read_csv(filepath,sep='s*',header=2,index_col=None, skiprows=2)
```

When I do this I get the following error:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 187,
>   in read_csv
>       return _read(TextParser, filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 160, in
>   _read
>       return parser.get_chunk()
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 613, in
>   get_chunk
>       raise Exception(err_msg)
>
> Exception: Index (columns 0) have duplicate values [nan]

Notice I have set the index column to None.  I've tried this using the first column as the index column and get the same error.  There are no empty lines in the data set or duplicated values in the first column.

Comment: What version are you using? try using 0.8.0rc2

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. Using 0.73. There wasn't any problem before up until today for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you use an arbitrary number of white spaces as a separator, you end up with different numbers of columns for each row.

In this case, this field in the header `2010/03/23 17:01:00`, will be converted to two columns. Now that the number of columns is differs between the header and the data, pandas assumes that it must index the first column. This is why you get the error. To fix it, you can try to specify a set number of white spaces as the delimiter. You can also use a comma or a tab or something else that will lead to unambiguous field delineation.